# How to get a button element made in the DOM, run a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created a button element using javascript, and now would like to know how to find that element or select it and get it to call this function:

```
    function test() {
      alert("it works!");  
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling `test()` from? Don't you have to bind an event to the button you created?

Comment: Do at least a little research. [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild), do some research on JavaScript tutorials or DOM tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way maybe.

```js
$("body").append("<button>Button</button>");

$("button").click(function(){
  alert("it works!");  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `addEventListener`:

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("ok");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

btn.addEventListener('click', test);

// My Test Function
function test() {
  alert("it works!");  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following to apply a click function to your button;

```
$(btn).on('click', test);
```

Answer (score 0):

*Another* option with jquery:

```js
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
var t = document.createTextNode("ok");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);

$('body').on('click', 'BUTTON', function(event) {
  alert("it works!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button is an object once you created it dynamically. This means that you and easily assign properties and functions to it using the dot syntax. So, for example, if you want to give the dynamic button onclick functionality, you could do this:

```
btn.onclick = function() { 
  // add the JS function you want on the dynamic button here
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
btn.onclick = function() { test(); }
var t = document.createTextNode("ok");
btn.appendChild(t);
document.body.appendChild(btn);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k30nf9oo/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at below snippet.

```js
var bIsCreated = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#createNewButton").on("click", createNewButton);
  $(document).on("click", ".newButton", function() {
    alert("I am a new button");
  });
});

function createNewButton() {
  if (!bIsCreated) {
    var $newButton = $("<button/>").addClass("newButton")
      .html("I am a new button");
    $newButton.appendTo(".container");
  }
  alert("I am a old button");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <button id="createNewButton"> Create a new button</button>
</div>
```